# android studio webView location

Tags: android, webview, permissions

I have an app that makes use of a webView, I need to request user permission for both location and camera as the website in the webView makes use of both, But the permission dialogs do not request permission, not sure what I'm missing. Even if I go into the app and accept app permissions on the device, it still does not allow.

Main Activity

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private String WebAddress = "https://www.example.com";
    private WebView webView;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private WebViewClient webViewClient;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private WebChromeClient webChromeClient;
    private GeolocationPermissions geolocationPermissions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                setTitle("Loading...");

                if (progress == 100){
                    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setTitle(view.getTitle());
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
            }



        });

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(WebAddress);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }


    private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            if (webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: For API level >23 you need to request permissions during runtime, just declaring them in the Manifest is not enough, read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Thank you for this, Ive added the following, now get the permission request to find the location, however it still reads an error when finding the location:


boolean permissionGranted = android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            if(permissionGranted) {
                // {Some Code}
            } else {
                android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
            }

Comment: So you do have your code instead of `// Some Code`? and you also overriden `onRequestPermissionResult`?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it, thats where I'm stuck, I'm not sure what to call there...

Comment: Instead of  `Some Code` you need to put the code that requires permission, your location code. Basically, with `checkSelfPermission` you ask if the permission is available, if `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, it means that you can execute your code, if it's not, then you request them with the line `requestPermissions`, and it goes to `onRequestPermissionResult` where you see if the permission was accepted, if it was you execute your code.